# Isolated or segregated workspaces / desktops / activities

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

What is a good solution for completely isolated workspaces?

Here is what I'm looking for:

- When I am in a workspace, I only stay in that workspace. I don't switch out to a different one, even if that other one is running the same programs as this one.
- When I close a workspace, it remembers all the apps that were open, and all the documents that were open in those apps (like websites in Firefox, documents in LibreOffice, etc). When I return to the workspace, it opens everything back up.

A key issue here is that this solution would be able to run multiple instances of all the apps, like Firefox.

If such a solution does not currently exist, what hacks or habits do you use to make your multitasking life easier? How do you keep your different tasks separate and all the apps set up for each task?

Comment: You could look into Virtual machines, containerization or multiple user account, I personaly prefer the first and third one

Comment: I want to try out the multiple accounts idea. I want to operate on the same set of files (home folder of account 1). This creates a problem every time I try to modify account 1 files as user 2. How do I set it up that user 2 is automatically always allowed to modify account 1 files? @Saxtheowl.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple accounts which look the better option here, you could simply create a shared group for both a user1 and user2

here is a way to do this, as root:

```
sudo groupadd shared
```

add the users

```
sudo usermod -aG shared user1
sudo usermod -aG shared user2
```

change the group ownership to the shared group

```
sudo chgrp -R shared /home/account1
```

Then give the write permission to the files to the group

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /home/account1
```

Comment: I'll try this. Sorry, I can't upvote because I'm a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you want to segregate you could consider to use LXD/LXC.

LXD is an orchestration/management interface to LXC containers, and those basically provide you a very light weight but very complete system within in own host system.

If you install x11-utils, yaru, and maybe a few other packages you can ssh into them (with X11 forwarding) and run GUI applications that you install such as Firefox. You can also have some folders shared between your host system and the container, in case you might need to share some files between them.

Comment: I'll investigate this if @Saxtheowl 's answer doesn't work for me.